# How to shorten a long line of code? Error ESlint

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I really need help. Installed ESlint and got the error "This line has a length of 262. Maximum allowed is 120 max-len". How can I shorten this line? When I just translate with Enter, the code just doesn't work.

```
     {
    actualTask: 'Актуальне питання? ',
    answer: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem 
    Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when anunknown 
    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
    },
```

[image]

Comment: why not use a back tick ``

Comment: @Codenewbie because that would not be the same string

Comment: so concatenate, no option :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just concatenate different parts of the string:

```
     {
    actualTask: 'Актуальне питання? ',
    answer: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem " +
    "Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when anunknown " +
    "printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using like this

```
 {
    actualTask: 'Актуальне питання? ',
    answer: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem 
    Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when anunknown 
    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.`
  }
```

Comment: This adds extra newlines and spaces where OP had none previously

Comment: while this solves the linter issue, this changes the original string by adding spaces and newlines

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JavaScript Template Literals/Template Strings](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp) for this purpose.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.